# alter form in Drupal to set default image

Tags: forms, drupal, hook, default, alter

I have a D7 form with an image file upload. I would like to provide an external url as the default image but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried using hook_form_alter:

```
function myapp_form_object_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
  $form['#node']->field_map_image['und'][0]['#default_value']['uri']="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Potsdamer_Platz,_Berlin,_151024,_ako.jpg"; 
}
```

but I get nothing. Any tips in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have to upload it over and over again for every new form submit without image set by user? Why don't you just set that field optional and at code which is displaying form results check is it uploaded or not and if it's not use that default image? Also maybe it would be good to copy image file to your server and use it from there.

Comment: No, I don't want it to be uploaded again and again. Each node has default values already filled in. So first, I'd like to know how best to assign that node's default image. Then I will use some sort of crop function to crop it... Any ideas? Is hook_form_alter the right way to go?

Comment: Then yes, hook_form_alter() is right way to go. And if you don't succeed to set default value for upload field (didn't try that, don't know will it work) you can use the same hook function to add extra form submit handler function, which can check if image is uploaded and if not set default value.